# Sending request to api failing on react

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, api, https

I sent a request to a face recognition API which is giving me error :

> Error:
>   HTTP403: FORBIDDEN - The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfil it.
>   (XHR)OPTIONS - https://api.clarifai.com/v2/models/c386b7a870114f4a87477c0824499348/outputs

**Request:**

```js
const app = new Clarifai.App({
  apiKey: '*********************'
});

app.models
    .predict("c386b7a870114f4a87477c0824499348", "https://samples.clarifai.com/wedding.jpg")
    .then(
    function(response) {
        console.log(response)
    },
    function(err) {
        console.log(error)
    }
);
```

Comment: is it a get request, did you tried calling this service in postman or some other tools. Try in that i think may be you are missing some headers which it requires

Comment: You should avoid adding `apiKeys` to your questions. These are essentially passwords and should be protected